# shopify script tag api is created and loaded but code is not executing

Tags: javascript, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm creating a shopify app but im facing some issues while working with script-tag api

I have created a script tag using this code:

```
    router.get("/scripts-tag/create",async (ctx)=>{
      ctx.body = await client.post({
        path: 'script_tags',
        data: {"script_tag":{"event":"onload","src":"https://xxxxx.ngrok.io/_next/static/chunks/pages/script-tag.js"}},
        type: DataType.JSON,
      });
    })
```

With this response:

```
  "body": {
    "script_tag": {
      "id": 173210206277,
      "src": "https://xxxxx.ngrok.io/_next/static/chunks/pages/script-tag.js",
      "event": "onload",
      "created_at": "2022-02-08T22:39:43+05:00",
      "updated_at": "2022-02-08T22:39:43+05:00",
      "display_scope": "all",
      "cache": false
    }
  },
  "headers": {}
}
```

script-tag.js:

```
import React from "react";

export default function scriptTag(){
    alert("hello")
}
```

i have also used this code before:

```
alert("hello world")
```

but the the real issue i'm facing is when i'm opening the store
[image: script is loaded in store]

you can see in the above image that script is loaded in store page but the script code  is not executed.

Comment: Have you checked in the console tab of your browser dev tool that there is no execution errors associated with your script?

Comment: thanks for replying i have solved this error by creating new folder "public" in root dir of shopify app and then created "script-tag.js" in that folder then it worked.